# Possible bug? Sculpt Mode -> Simplify Brush is affecting far side of mesh

Tags: sculpting

I am using the simplify brush with dynamic topology turned on, so that I can manually remesh my object, which is a head.

Everything works until I get to the ear, and try to reduce triangle density on the back of the ear (while leaving the front unchanged).

The problem I'm getting is that sometimes the brush punches through and starts operating on the far face. Even though I've checked "front faces only".

[image]

You can in the picture; I've been editing the back of the ear, and I've just turned it round to inspect the damage.

I'm guessing this is because the ear is thin?

Anyway, is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Are all your normals correct?

Comment: You should first figure out if this is a bug or not, (posting a sample blend would help) - or even just reporting this to blenders bug tracker.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It can be a bug, or something in developement.

For you question: You can use various Mask tools / operations to temporally "block" the areas from being affected. For example, There is a brush type called **Mask** (or press <kbd>M</kbd> to switch to it), and also a menu category called **Hide/Mask** on the 3d View header when in **Sculpt** mode.

However, to quickly meet what you need, you can <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> to drag the block area (it will be shown in dark grey). Then just paint. When finishing, clear the mask by <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>.

[image]

[image]

Comment: What have you done to poor Suzanne!? ;)

Comment: True, I'm feeling guilty, sorry...  :P

Comment: I'm curious, what *did* you do in the top image? (for the weird deformations I mean, not the masking)

Comment: W > Subdivide Smooth (x3). It got different result as a 3-level Subsurf modifier. Yes, a bit weird, probably caused by the different algorithm? A [bit more tweak](http://www.pasteall.org/pic/show.php?id=64923) would be of more fun. :P